# SwiftUI half Donut Chart

Tags: charts, swiftui, donut-chart

**I made full donut chart but I couldn't make half donut chart. How Can I do this ?**

Sorry, my english is poor. I want to make a chart in the form of a half donut.

[image]

[image]

**Half Donut Chart**

```
struct HalfDonutChart : View {
    @ObservedObject var charDataObj = ChartDataContainer()
    @State var indexOfTappedSlice = -1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<charDataObj.chartData.count) { index in
                    Circle()
                    .trim(from: index == 0 ? 0.0 : charDataObj.chartData[index-1].value/100,
                              to: charDataObj.chartData[index].value/100)
                        .stroke(charDataObj.chartData[index].color,lineWidth: 50)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            indexOfTappedSlice = indexOfTappedSlice == index ? -1 : index
                        }
                        .scaleEffect(index == indexOfTappedSlice ? 1.1 : 1.0)
                        .animation(.spring())
                }
                if indexOfTappedSlice != -1 {
                    Text(String(format: "%.2f", Double(charDataObj.chartData[indexOfTappedSlice].percent))+"%")
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
            .padding()
            .onAppear() {
                self.charDataObj.calc()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Chart Data Container:**

```
class ChartDataContainer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var chartData =
        [ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4932718873, blue: 0.4739984274, alpha: 1)), percent: 8, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8323456645, blue: 0.4732058644, alpha: 1)), percent: 15, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4508578777, green: 0.9882974029, blue: 0.8376303315, alpha: 1)), percent: 32, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.476841867, green: 0.5048075914, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), percent: 45, value: 0)]
  
    func calc(){
        var value : CGFloat = 0
        
        for i in 0..<chartData.count {
            value += chartData[i].percent
            chartData[i].value = value
        }
    }
}
```

**Chart Data Model:**

```
struct ChartData {
    var id = UUID()
    var color : Color
    var percent : CGFloat
    var value : CGFloat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trimming by the value / 100 implies that you are representing 100 with a full circle. For half a circle, you'd need to divide by 200. You can then add a `.rotationEffect(.degrees(-180))` to the `ForEach` to get things the correct way round.